# biblatex: how to make \fullcite a clickable link

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I am using `biblatex` to cite articles with full reference in the text, and therefore have no references section.

The `biblatex` setup that I use is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
    @article{reference,
    author = {F Author and S Author}, 
    journal = {Obsc. J.},
    title = {Article Title},
    pages = {13},
    volume = {400},
    year = {2013},
    month = {Oct},
    doi = {10.1111/123},
    URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/123}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[maxnames=1,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,firstinits=true,uniquename=false,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{year}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % italic journal title 
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % remove "in:"
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{, }
\renewcommand{\newblockpunct}{, }
% remove first name
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{\usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}} % remove title


\begin{document}
Cite the article \fullcite{reference}.
\end{document}
```

This way, a reference cited with `\fullcite` gives something like "Author et al., *Obsc. J.* 400 (2013), 13".

So far so good, but now I would like to make the citation (or at least the first author if thats easier) a hyperlink leading to the URL of the article (each article entry in the bib-file has a URL entry and/or a DOI). Is there a way to do this?

Edit: something similar is used in the reference section of some Journals, see e.g. [this open access article](http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/725/1/1/pdf/0004-637X_725_1_1.pdf).

Comment: What is it a clickable link to, if you have no bibliography?

Comment: I mean a hyperlink that opens the URL in a browser

Comment: So every item in your `.bib` file has a URL, and you want `biblatex` to generate the link from the `.bib` file itself.

Comment: yes, at least it might have a DOI from which one could get a URL by using http://dx.doi.org/`DOI`

Comment: Ok. Since not everyone reads the comments, it might be helpful to update your question to explain that that's what you want. Also, if a bib entry has a URL and a DOI which should be in the link?

Comment: Can't you load `hyperref` and remove one of the two options `doi=false` or `url=false`? BTW: why do you have both `doi` and `url` fields (they point to the same place)?

Comment: If I turn those options on, then I get the doi and/or url printed inline, like "Author et al., *Obsc. J.* 400 (2013), 13, `doi: 10.1111/123`, `url: http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/123`."

The doi is always just the doi number, the url is sometimes a link to the dx.doi.org, sometimes a direct link to the journal website, this depends on which metadata my bibliography program read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of redefining each and every field format you might like this more general approach to redefine the `\fullcite` command.

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
      {\usedriver
       {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
       {\thefield{entrytype}}}
      {\href{\thefield{url}}
        {\usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}}}
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

This will link the full citation as printed by the bibdriver to the `DOI`-URL or `URL` (in that order of precedence).

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{reference,
  author = {F Author and S Author}, 
  journal = {Obsc. J.},
  title = {Article Title},
  pages = {13},
  volume = {400},
  year = {2013},
  month = {10},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/123},
  doi = {10.1111/123},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[maxnames=1,backend=bibtex,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,firstinits=true,uniquename=false,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{year}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % italic journal title 
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % remove "in:"
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\newblockpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{\usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}} % remove title

\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\iffieldundef{doi}
    {\iffieldundef{url}
      {\usedriver
       {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
       {\thefield{entrytype}}}
      {\href{\thefield{url}}
        {\usedriver
          {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
          {\thefield{entrytype}}}}}
    {\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{\usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Cite the article \fullcite{reference}.
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Note though that I would not wholeheartedly recommend this, as it seems to be better to actually be able to see the `doi`/`url` linked somewhere in the document. After all, on paper there is no way to tell where a link is going.

Answer (score 1):

I found an intermediate solution: adding the `hyperref` package and replacing above declarations with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{#1}}
\DeclareNameFormat{first-last}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/\thefield{doi}}{\usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}\usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
```

makes the author name, journal name, year, pages, and volume number individual urls. It's not perfect but it gets the job done.